# firebase-angular2 mapping issue

Tags: firebase, angular

Angular 2 is fairly new. I have been using firebase-angular2 to create a service.
I ran the firebase-angular2 demo here https://github.com/KallynGowdy/firebase-angular2-demo but when I have been running it I get the following error

EXCEPTION: TypeError: heroes.map is not a function
angular2.dev.js:23083 EXCEPTION: TypeError: heroes.map is not a function

As far as I can tell it is referring to this section of code at ts/firebase-heros.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "../../node_modules/angular2/core";
import {HeroService} from "./hero.service";
import {Observable} from "../../node_modules/rxjs/Rx";
import {FirebaseService} from '../../node_modules/firebase-angular2/core';
import {Hero} from "./../interfaces/hero";

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseHeroService extends HeroService {

private service:FirebaseService;

constructor(firebaseService:FirebaseService) {
    this.service = firebaseService.child('heroes');
}

getHeroes() {
    var service = this.service;
    return service.value.map((heroes) => {
        return heroes.map((h, i) => {
            // TODO: Cleanup
            return {
                id: h.id,
                name: h.name,
                save: function () {
                    return service.child(i.toString()).setData({
                        id: this.id,
                        name: this.name
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
}
```

Any ideas of what may be causing this problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heroes` is not array at this line, that's why you're getting an error:

```
return service.value.map((heroes) => {
  console.log(heroes);
  ...
```

If you log it's value you can check what type it is and take appropriate action. If it's a response, you might need to convert it to JSON before processing it further

```
return service.value
 .map(response => response.json())
 .map((heroes) => {...
```